# java signature verification

Tags: java, digital-signature

I am getting the  exception ,

java.security.SignatureException: invalid encoding for signature

in my program . the following is the code snippet

```
Signature sig=Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithDSA");
sig.initVerify(qakeyPair.getPublic());
sig.update(data.getBytes());
sig.verify(sig_bytes)
```

why is this happening..?

Answer (score 2):

The contents of `sig_bytes` are not a valid signature according to what the algorithm expects. Perhaps they're the byte representation of a base64 or hex encoded signature rather than the decoded signature data.